How is the local field in a dielectric material calculated?
I have read in different sources (text, video, amongst others) that the local field in a dielectric material placed within a capacitor can be easily calculated as the sum of 4 electric fields: $E_{external}$, $E_{dielectic}$, $E_{atom}$, $E_{cavity}$, where these are:

$E_{dielectic}$ - external field;
$E_{dielectic}$ - host dielectic material field
$E_{atom}$ - atomic electric field (annuled due to 3D lattice symmetry)
$E_{cavity}$ - electric field of the vaccuum cavity where the atomic lattice is theorised to be -  via a bunch 3D intregrations, this results in $\frac{P}{3\epsilon_0}$, where $P$ is the polarisation.

I am struggling to understand how to the first two fields, $E_{external}$ and $E_{dielectic}$, are calculated. Some sources solve this by simply stating that these two fields add up to an electric field, $E$. But this seems like an oversimplification, but other sources (such as the aforementioned video, amongst others I currently cannot find), state that the displacement field, $D$ can be represented in two different, yet similar equations:
$ D = \epsilon_0 E_{external}\tag{1}$
$ D = \epsilon_0 E + P \tag{2}$
where $P$ is the polarisation and  $\epsilon_0$ the vacuum permittivity; and that by equating this, we obtain,
$ E_{external} = E + \frac{P}{\epsilon_0}\tag{3}$
and somehow
$E_{dielectric} = \frac{-P}{\epsilon_0} \tag{4}$
What field does $E$ correspond to? Is this the field in a vacuum? And if this is the case, shouldn't equation ${2}$ have a different permittivity for the dielectric material in question?
What guarantees the conservation of $D$?
Is $E_{dielectric}$ obtained solely from assuming that the response will be the polar opposite? Or is there mathematical evidence for equation 4 to be true?
PS: I understand that equation (1) is for non-polarised materials, and that (2) is for polarised one, but I don't understand why these are equal and have the same permittivity.

Oh, this horrible thing. One nice way to think of it is this: Consider the sample dielectric being subjected to uniform external E field. Then that causes "surface charges" polarisation which serves to decrease the average field felt inside the material. This is what you subtract. This gives us a view of the average internal field of the sample, removing the geometrical behaviour of how big the sample is, etc. Now, imagine the sample is infinitely large, so that the average internal field is all there is;

And then you can remove the smooth averaging in a ball centred on the origin. This removal then induces polarisation "surface charges" on the spherical shell, which you have to add back. Now you have the empty ball, from which you add back the crystalline lattice of ions and electrons, or atoms, or what have you. Compute the relationship that you ought to get, that connects the average internal field, to the field as felt by an atom, and thereby obtain the ab initio quantum corrections to the dielectric constant. Then let the ball be infinitely large, if you want to be precise.
